# How to call ArrayAdapter.addAll method in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a very simple list (so it isn't necessary to create a custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter). I use an ArrayApdater to implements this.

When I want to change the value of the adapter, there's a build error says there's two allAll methods and kotlin don't know which one to use.

Here's the sample code:

```
    val list = Collections.emptyList<Any>() // Just for sample.
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<Any>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list) // This line is OK
    // Some work later
    adapter.clear()
    adapter.addAll(list) // Here's the error
```

The error message is :

```
    Error:(79, 35) Overload resolution ambiguity:
    public open fun addAll(p0: (MutableCollection<out Any!>..Collection<Any!>?)): Unit defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    public open fun addAll(vararg p0: Any!): Unit defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `addAll` methods in `ArrayAdapter`:

1. `ArrayAdapter.addAll(T ... items)`
2. `public void addAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends T> collection)`.

so compiler is unable to infer which one method you want to call, because `Any` is somewhat like `Object` in Java.

Instead of :
`val list = Collections.emptyList<Any>()` use `val list = Collections.emptyList<String>()`.

And change `ArrayAdapter<Any>` to `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Error should be resolved.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `String` instead of `Any`

Your code should be like this.

```
val list = Collections.emptyList<String>() // Just for sample.
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list) // This line is OK
        // Some work later
        adapter.clear()
        adapter.addAll()
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension method:

```
inline fun <T> ArrayAdapter<T>.addAllCollection(c: Collection<T>) = this.addAll(c)
```

Calling an extension method can bypass this limitation:

```
adapter.addAllCollection(list)
```